# App crashes when button tapped with testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm developing app with Swift 4.2 and I have problems with iOS app crash.
For me everything works fine, but it doesn't work for others who installed app with testflight.
Error is like this.
[image]

Here's a code that adds handler.

```
cell.btnBooknow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBookNowButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Here is a button click handler.

```
@objc func pressBookNowButton(button: UIButton) {
    guard let tagValue = self.arrListingBagHandler.object(at: button.tag) else {
        return
    }
    print(self.artworks)

    print(self.onlineStatus)
    print(self.arrSearchAddressResult)


    print(tagValue)
    let valueStatus = tagValue["IsOnline"] as! String
    let availability = tagValue["AvailabilityDays"] as! String
    let arr = Array(availableDays)
    print(valueStatus)
    print(arr)
    let arrAvailability = Array(availability)
    print(arrAvailability)
    let arr1 = availability.components(separatedBy: ",")
    print(arr1)

    let day = (presentDay!-1)
    let today = "\(day)"
    print(today)
    if arr1.contains(today)
    {
        availableToday = true
    }
    else
    {
        availableToday = false
    }

    if valueStatus == "1" && availableToday == true
    {
        let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookingId") as! BookingViewController
        obj.dicBagHanlderDetail = tagValue
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
    }
    else 
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "You can't make booking because store is currently closed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { (actoin) in
        }
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Sharing the code of that method might help. Also, you could try to install the release version on your phone.

Comment: Yes, for me it's working, but on the client's phone, it crashes.

Comment: It crashed on a iOS 12.1 iPhone 6 Plus. Can you try that in this configuration? Also, we can't guess what's wrong without code.

Comment: Here's a code that adds handler. cell.btnBooknow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressBookNowButton(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: @ZhengGeChe at first line you try to force conversion to `[ string : Any ]` will you please use `guard let`

Comment: Copy paste code, not screenshot of code. Any use of `!` is a potential reason of crash. Use `if let` or `guard let`, don't force unwrap. Also if you install it yourself through TestFlight, can you reproduce the crash?

Comment: Why you pass the cell data through button tag, its not the good way to do this, cause maybe the data will be deallocated then it crashes when you use of `!` to parse data.
try to read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1) which shows how to pass data from cell which will solve this crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below function and resolve an issue. I think it is possible because of the force cast string and int value.

```
@objc func pressBookNowButton(button: UIButton) {
guard let tagValue = self.arrListingBagHandler.object(at: button.tag) else {
    return
}




let valueStatus = tagValue["IsOnline"] as? String ?? ""
let availability = tagValue["AvailabilityDays"] as? String ?? ""
let arr = Array(availableDays)

let arrAvailability = Array(availability)

let arr1 = availability.components(separatedBy: ",")

let value : Int = Int(presentDay) ?? 0
let day = (value-1)
let today = "\(day)"

if arr1.contains(today)
{
    availableToday = true
}
else
{
    availableToday = false
}

if valueStatus == "1" && availableToday == true
{
    let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookingId") as! BookingViewController
    obj.dicBagHanlderDetail = tagValue
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
}
else
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "You can't make booking because store is currently closed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { (actoin) in
    }
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested any `!` is a potential crash. Try to replace it with guard or default values. For example you can change:

```
let valueStatus = tagValue["IsOnline"] as! String
let availability = tagValue["AvailabilityDays"] as! String
```

To solution with default values:

```
let valueStatus = tagValue["IsOnline"] as? String ?? "1"
let availability = tagValue["AvailabilityDays"] as? String ?? "5"
```

Or even better guard and e.g. display alert if data aren't available:

```
guard let valueStatus = tagValue["IsOnline"] as? String,
    let availability = tagValue["AvailabilityDays"] as? String else {
    // Display alert in case of unavailable data (or simply return)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "You can't make booking because store is currently closed.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { _ in }
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
// Continue as expected here...
```

Comment: Yeah, thats would work but will lead to wrong behaviour, which makes the user book wrongly. I think the crash happens cause the data return `nil`, so I think its good if he could debug why this return `nil`, maybe the way he is passing the tag from the cell.